# Ajax.BeginForm() set javascript variable on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have ajax form as follows:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddMyModel", "MyModel",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnBegin = "begin",
    OnComplete = "end",
    UpdateTargetId = "addcontent",
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter
},
new
{
    id = "validationForm",
    @class = "edit_form",
   style = "width: 400px;"
}))
{
<div id="addcontent">
    @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView", Model)
</div>
}
```

when I submit the form, it goes to the function AddMyModel in MyModel controller.

**What I want:**
In case of error in function AddMyModel to set a javascript variable that I can check after it in the javascript function end like that.

MyJavascriptFile.js:

```
var success;

function end()
{
   if(success==false)
   {
         //I know there was error
   }
}
```

is it possible? is it sound reasonable or error prone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the OnFailure option in your `AjaxOptions` collection:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddMyModel", "MyModel",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnBegin = "begin",
    OnComplete = "end",
    OnFailure = "handleError(error)",
    UpdateTargetId = "addcontent",
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter
},
```

And then:

```
function handleError(error)
{
   //error handling logic
}
```

It is a very common practice to handle such kind of errors in this way.

If you want to be able to decide yourself whether an action is successful or not you could write the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) // for example
    {
        return Json(new { success = false });
    }
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Then modify your `OnSuccess` function:

```
OnComplete = "end(result)"
```

And then handle the error-checking as a part of your `success` function:

```
function end(result) {
    if (result.success) {
        // executed when successful
    } else {
        // executed when you decided it is not successful
    }
}
```

Comment: very good answer! thank you! I changed the end(result) to end(xhr) and it worked... because end(result) not recognize result...